# flask - retrieve data from a sqlite3 db

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have a table in a sqlite3 db called `syncano.db` with a table called `toto` : 2 columns named `col1`and `col2`.

I'm trying to display everything inside of the table toto.

Here is the script in `views.py`

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app
import sqlite3
from flask import g

DATABASE = '/Users/admin/syncano/app/syncano.db'

def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = connect_to_database()
    return db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()


@app.route('/toto')
def toto(subject_id):
    entries = query_db('select col1,col2 from toto where col1 = grand test')
    return render_template('show_results.html', entries = entries)

def query_db(query):
    cur = g.db.execute(query)
    rv = [dict((cur.description[idx][0], value)
        for idx, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv
```

And here is my file `show_results.html``

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    <ul class=entries>
        {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><h2>{{ entry }}</h2>
        <br>
        {% else %}
        <li><em>No entry here</em>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endblock %}   
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Issue is the page cannot be displayed and I have a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Does anyone knows what is happening?

**Edit:** `run.py`

```
#!bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: That error sounds more like it has to do with the server not starting correctly. Can you share the code that creates the `app`?

Comment: @wilfo: does it sound what you are looking for?

Comment: You have a typo in your query. You need to wrap strings in your query inside quotes. `col1 = "grand test"`

Comment: @dirn : amended . issue is still ongoing.

Comment: You need to show us the logs from `run.py`. Flask's error(s) will be in there.

Comment: @dirn: where I can find that, please?

Comment: In the terminal where you execute it.

Comment: also, where's your `connect_to_database` function code?

Comment: @dirn : it does not like the " or the '. It gives me this `File "/Users/admin/syncano/app/views.py", line 23
    entries = query_db('select col1,col2 from toto where col1 = 'grand test')
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @wilfo: check at the beginning of `Here is the script in views.py`

Comment: try: `query_db("select col1,col2 from toto where col1 = 'grand test'")`

Comment: @wilfo : much better. Please find the log http://pastebin.com/jXHNZ3bp

Comment: Take a look at the error: `TypeError: toto() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`. the function you defined to deal with calls to `/toto` expects a parameter: `subject_id`.
passing parameters to route methods in Flask explicitly says they need to be present in the route you're using. 
So, your should be using something of the sort of: `/toto/<subject_id>`